# Problem with standalone with beamer and pdfx

Tags: beamer, standalone, pdfx

I have been drawing many `tikzpictures` this way:

```
\documentclass[beamer,preview,tikz]{standalone} 

%\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{standaloneframe}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \only<1>{\node {1};}
      \only<2>{\node {2};}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

Now, I like to make this pictures PDF/A compatible, but the code does not compile with `\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}`:

> ! Package kvsetkeys Error: Undefined key `pdftex,pdfa,pdfversion=1.4'.
>   ...  ! pdfTeX error (setup): \pdfminorversion cannot be changed after
>   data is written to the PDF file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `\RequirePackage{pdf14}` before `\documentclass`.

Comment: @TeXnician: Unfortunatley, this does not work, i.e., nothing has changed.

Comment: To better understand your question, can you explain your train of thoughts why this error comes from an option clash of `hyperref`?

Comment: I have no idea where the error comes from. Ohh .. I see. The title of my post is not correct. I will change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I tried right now is:

```
\AtEndOfClass{\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}}
```

What ever this does .. it compiles now (by accident)! I will try this on all my 70 tikzpictures.

But it would be helpful if someone could comment if this is "a right way" to go. Thanks.

Comment: The first error is due to a bug in pdfx, it calls \hypersetup for a command and forgets to expand it. The second more fatal error is an incompability between beamer and pdfx, it opens the pdf and so pdfx can't make its settings. Your \AtEndOfClass is the only chance.